# Relocate using JavaScript with TypeScript

Tags: javascript, typescript, relocation

I want to do a simple relocate using javascript and typescript. Using the following code

```
window.location = 'index.html';
```

that does what it should, I still get a TypeScript-error that says

```
Assigned expression type string is not assinable to type Location
```

What is the *supposed* way to do this relocate correctly with TypeScript?

Comment: Yep, that helped - it's indeed a duplicate. Thanks a lot.